# Подключение к папкам nextcloud по webdav в Windows 7/10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, webdav, nextcloud

Имеется ли возможность подключить сетевой диск через Microsoft Windows Explorer?
 Сам nextcloud крутится на ubuntu server 16.04.

Рекомендуемый вариант:

> https://example.com/nextcloud/remote.php/dav/files/USERNAME/

никоим образом не срабатывает. В nautilus на ubuntu все работает.

Comment: Подтверждаю, не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Всё прекрасно работает
Только вместо USERNAME нужно указать имя пользователя с учетом регистра